# How do I set axes to add text outside a plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

(Using python3.4)

This is the code I'm using to plot. I'm trying to add additional text which can help explain what this plot is about.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
somecode.....
somecode.....
xv=np.array(x1)
yv=np.array(y1)
txt='''
Text to be printed outside the plot
Text to be printed outside the plot
Text to be printed outside the plot
Text to be printed outside the plot
Text to be printed outside the plot
'''
plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(yv,zv, label="Cap vs Percentage Diff", color="m")
plt.xlabel('Latest Cap in FF')
plt.ylabel('Percentage Diff')
plt.title('Variable Cap')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.text(0.95, 0.95, txt)
```

I used plt.text to print the text 0.95 below the X-axis the and 0.95 away from Y axis. But matplotlib is picking the co-ordinates relative to the graph.

This issue is reported on couple of other threads and most of the answers are explained using plt.text format.

Is there a way to print text beyond the axis?

As a work around I'm currently adding this information to plt.xlabel so that it can be printed under the x-axis label. But, I'd like to know the possibilities to add text outside the plot by not specifying the co-ordinates.

Reason I don't want to use/Specify X, Y co-ordinates is, XY coordinates can be negative values in the data I'm reading in.

I tried to understand the syntax and usage from documentation but it is far beyond my expertise as I started using python fairly couple of weeks ago.

Appreciate if any one can explain/tell how to use text and figtext to add data outside the plot.

And does both text and figtext need axes info?

Current plot displays the image without the text I want to add outside the plot

[image]

Required plot style: I'd like to the stddev, avg, min and max under the x-label of subplot:

[image]

Thanks

Edit 1: Adding original code.

```
import matplotlib
import sys
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

x1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
y1=[5, 6, 7, 8]
z1=[9, 10 ,11, 12]

xv=np.array(x1)
yv=np.array(y1)
zv=np.array(z1)
#Find Max, Min, Avg and StdDev for the delta(C) i.e. zv numpy array
MaxCapDiff      =str (np.amax(zv))
MinCapDiff      =str (np.amin(zv))
AvgOfCapDiff        =str (np.average(zv))
StdDevOfCapDiff     =str (np.std(zv))

print ('Max Cap Diff in Percent:'+MaxCapDiff) print ('Min Cap Diff in          Percent:'+MinCapDiff) print ('Avg of Cap Difference  :'+AvgOfCapDiff)
print ('STD DEV of Cap Diff    :'+StdDevOfCapDiff)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.scatter(xv,yv, label="Cap vs Cap")
plt.xlabel('Golden Cap in (FF)')
plt.ylabel('Latest Cap in (FF)')
plt.title('Cap Comparison')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(212)
plt.scatter(yv,zv, label="Cap vs Percentage Diff", color="m")
plt.xlabel('Latest cap in (FF)') plt.ylabel('Percentage Diff')
plt.title('Variable Cap')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('plot.jpg')
plt.show()
```